# On key release handler

Tags: vb.net, keypress, keyup, eventhandler

So, what I'm trying to do is run a piece of code when a button is pressed (I'll use the right-arrow key for the time being), and keep running it in a loop until that key is released.

So, my current code looks something like this (I've simplified it, because it's using SerialPorts, and is not easy to understand code):

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown

    Select Case e.KeyCode

        Case Keys.Right

            Do Until (CODE LOOKING FOR RIGHT-ARROW KEY RELEASE)
                SerialPort1.Write("right")
            Loop

            e.Handled = True
            SerialPort1.Close()
End Sub
```

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is control and arduino through the serial port function. I've wired it up to a cheap rc car (I usually have a few arduino projects on the go), and have code which allows me to control it by arrow keys in the IDE itself.

However, I have limited VB.NET knowledge (I've only been at it a few years), so I'm kinda struggling along with the help of Google, which was a god end while trying to work out how to keep the serialport open (it kept closing due to a logic error in my code).

The goal is that once I can control it by arrow keys in VB.NET, I can set up a more advanced program which will allow pre-programming routes (for example, I can try to "teach" the car sets of instructions so that I can get it to automatically follow a circuit, and load various pre-programmed routes into it). I'd also plan an on-screen gui to show what button was pressed, and whatever else I think of.

Also, given this is a prototype, I intend to eventually hook up the arduino and VB program to my hobby grade rc, and see if I can get the computer program, with pre-programmed isntructions, to beat my round my track.

Well, after that little essay, I guess it's just thanks in advance, and any advice in other areas of my project is also appreciated =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controling the Moving PictureBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22861825/controling-the-moving-picturebox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why make this complicated.  It looks like you want to send something as long as the key is down, and then close the port when it is released.

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right AndAlso keydelay >= 1 Then
        Debug.WriteLine("DWN") 'SerialPort1.Write("right")
        e.Handled = True
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        keydelay += 1
    End If
End Sub

Dim keydelay As Integer = 0

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Right Then
        keydelay = 0
        Debug.WriteLine("UP") 'SerialPort1.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to work from my testing (I can't actually test it with my arduino till later), will advise on it's success.

Comment: im coming across the issue that there is a pause between the first time it sends something through serial port, and the rest. For example, I press the UP arrow key, it moves the car a little forward, pauses, then moves it smoothly forward again.

Comment: ah, I kept pressing the arrow, and it was saying not enough reputation. got it :)