# (VB) How to detect a keypress only once, even when holding the key down?

Tags: vb.net, keypress, keydown

I have been working on a large game project lately and have been though a couple methods for detecting keyboard input. For movement I use getasynckeystate (which is perfect) because it sends a signal every tick that the key is being pressed.

Then comes the other method, which is keydown. This method works with single keypresses, but then a second later starts spamming the keypress action.

My goal is to find something that will only detect your keypress once, even if you hold down the key; once you let go of the key it will let you hit it again. Please help and thanks for reading this!

Examples:

if GetAsyncKeyState(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.W)) then....
if e.keycode = keys.B then....

Comment: This is normal, the key starts to repeat when you hold it down.  Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh.  Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22866098/17034).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'keyUp' event captures the key that was pressed or which remained pressed only once:

```
Sub Control_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Control.KeyUp
        MsgBox("Pressed key: " & e.KeyCode.ToString())
End Sub
```

Edit: Removed Private access so it can be called from another class.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks a bunch! On another note is there a way to call this sub from a class other than the main one?

Comment: You can do this: Call Control_KeyUp (Me, New KeyEventArgs (Keys.A)), here I am sending the A key to the Sub.

Comment: Thank you for your response but unfortunately that code will not work for what i'm trying to do. Basically, I am trying to make this sub in a class outside main, so the "control.keyup" part makes an error and visual studio wants a "WithEvents" variable.

Comment: It is advisable to capture keyboard events through the form first, and then through the controls, so I suggest you use: `Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Form1.KeyUp`.

Comment: You can make a call from another class like this for example:
`Call Form1.Control_KeyUp (Me, New KeyEventArgs (Keys.A))`
But the KeyUp event of Form1 should not be `Private`.

Comment: I found a solution that worked perfect, all I did was call a sub from another class (at the end of the keyup sub) and had e as an argument. From the external sub I could carry out many if statements without crowding the main keyup sub :)

Comment: Good, you kept trying until you get it.